# Invoking sagemaker endpoint with CustomAttributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to invoke my SageMaker endpoint and pass CustomAttributes argument specified [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html#SageMakerRuntime.Client.invoke_endpoint).

what I want to know is how to retrieve the CustomAttributes in the model endpoint?

I created an inference.py file for my endpoint that has the following structure:

```
imports

def get_device():
    device = 'cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    return device

def model_fn(model_dir):
    return model

def transform_fn(model, request_body, content_type, accept)
   return json.dumps(predictions)
```

just as request_body, content_type, accept are passed to transform_fn, i want to pass the CustomAttributes. Is this possible and if so how can i do it ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is convenient to structure the inference code by having full control of all the underlying steps.

As the documentation "[Adapting Your Own Inference Container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/adapt-inference-container.html)" suggests, you can arrange 4 functions: `model_fn`, `input_fn`, `predict_fn` and `output_fn`.

Beyond these, you can create your own handler to handle all the attributes you pass when you invoke an endpoint ("[How to implement the pre- and/or post-processing handler(s)](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.html#how-to-implement-the-pre-and-or-post-processing-handler-s)").

You can have the `input_handler` / `output_handler` **pair** of functions or a **single** `handler` function.

---

Below is an example of code for a generic inference script.

Inside your block of endpoint's invocation:

```py
import boto3
import json

runtime = boto3.Session().client('sagemaker-runtime')

runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(
    EndpointName = your_endpoint_name,
    Body = your_data,
    CustomAttributes = json.dumps(your_attributes_dict),
    ContentType = your_content_type
)
```

and inside your inference.py:

```py
import json

def handler(data, context):
    processed_input = _process_input(data, context)
    custom_attrs = json.loads(context.custom_attributes)

    # here place your function to parse and use your custom_attrs json

    response = requests.post(context.rest_uri, data=processed_input)
    return _process_output(response, context)

def _process_input(data, context):
   # your _process_input to decode the request_content_type

    if context.request_content_type == YOUR_CONTEXT_TYPE:
        return your_process_func(data)

    raise ValueError('{{"error": "unsupported content type {}"}}'.format(
        context.request_content_type or "unknown"))

def _process_output(data, context):
    if data.status_code != 200:
        raise ValueError(data.content.decode('utf-8'))

    response_content_type = context.accept_header
    prediction = data.content
    return prediction, response_content_type
```

---

**Pay attention to this note:**

> Note that if handler function is implemented, input_handler and
> output_handler are ignored.

It means that if you use a framework like TensorFlow or PyTorch, you will have to see how to override these methods starting from their default handlers.

Comment: do you mind letting me know what happens to the ```input_fn``` if I post the data as multipart/form-data where the body is json.dumps{'key': <byte array>} ? I have been debugging this part for a few tries.